# Styled-components: Interpolated function or component.extend?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

In styled-component, how do you decide whether you should use interpolated function to modify component ( by passing props ) or extend the existing component. For example:

```
const Button = styled.button`
    color: palevioletred;
    font-size: 1em;
    margin: 1em;
    padding: 0.25em 1em;
    border: 2px solid palevioletred;
    border-radius: 3px;
`;

// We're extending Button with some extra styles
const TomatoButton = Button.extend`
    color: tomato;
    border-color: tomato;
`;

render(
    <div>
        <Button>Normal Button</Button>
        <TomatoButton>Tomato Button</TomatoButton>
    </div>
);
```

We could have used interpolated function also. How do you decide between the two?

Answer (score 0):

It different, by passing a props we can use it in other situation but if using extends we just use it as an extra style for a new component something like inherit. Example: for nav menu, if there is an active menu, you dont need to use extends. Just use active class using props.So you dont need to do extend or make new component.